# "Think it well to" - meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I have encountered a phrase "think sth well" and I cannot seem to find any sources explaining the meaning:

> The demon thought it well to conceal his consternation.

Does it mean to "think sth through"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence means

> The demon thought that it would be well if he concealed his consternation.

The resemblance to "well thought out" is a coincidence.  One can "think [something] well" on the spur of a moment when the briefest reflection would reveal that it would be much worse than other actions.

Answer (score 3):

One of the [definitions of **well**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well) as an adjective is, "advisable, desirable."  That is the sense it is being used here, so "to think something well" means that you believe that thing is a good idea.

Personally, I find this usage to be a bit dated and uncommon in modern American English. Google Ngram finds that the [usage of the phrase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think%20it%20well&year_start=1800&year_end=2019) "think it well" peaked around 1880.